# One-Sided Inverse of a Complex Polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I encountered the following question in complex analysis:

Let $P(z)$ be a polynomial such that if $P(z)\in \mathbb{D}$ then $z\in \mathbb{D}$ and $P'(z)\neq 0$. Prove that there exists an analytic function $f(z)$ on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $P(f(z))=z$ for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$.

The question seems innocuous but I am not sure where to start with. It is supposed to be solved using some analytic continuation and Riemann surface knowledge. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure that the statement is correct as one can take $P(z)=\frac{(z-2)^2}{100}$ which obviously satisfies the conditions, but if $P(f(z))=z$ for all $z \in \mathbb D$, $f(0)=2$ and then taking derivatives $f'(0)P'(2)=1$ but $P'(2)=0$; maybe you want $f(P(z))=z$?

Comment: Sorry I think there is indeed a typo in the statement. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

Since $P$ is a polinomial, it is surjective, and thus $\forall z \in \mathbb{D}\ f^{-1}(\{z\})\neq \emptyset$. Thanks to the hypotesis, we obtain that $f^{-1}(\{z\})\in \mathbb{D}$. Thus $P: P^{-1}(\mathbb{D})\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{D}$. Also, since $P'(z)\neq 0$, $P$ is locally invertible, i.e. given a point $z\in \mathbb{D}$ there exists a function  $f$ defined in a neighbourhood of $z$ which satisfies $P\circ f=\text{Id}$.

1. Proof by means of the monodromy theorem:

Let us define $f_0$ as a local inverse of $P$ at $0$ (i.e. $P(f(0))=0$), defined on the open ball $U_0$. Given a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{D}$, we can extend $f_0$ on this path:
To prove it, let $\Omega$ be the subinterval of $[0,1]$ such that $\gamma_{|\Omega}$ admits an analytic continuation of $f_0$.

- $\Omega$ is non-empty, as it contains $0$.
- $\Omega$ is closed , since given a cluster point $t$, we can define the analytic continuation in a neighborhood of $\gamma(t)$ as a local inverse of $P$ compatible with the analytic continuations in $\gamma(t^*);t^*<t$
- $\Omega$ is open, since for every $t$ the analytic continuation $(f_t,U_t)$ in $\gamma(t)$ is also valid in $\gamma^{-1}(U_t)$ .

Thus $\Omega=[0,1]$, and $f_0$ can be analytically extended along every path in $\mathbb{D}$.  Since $\mathbb{D}$ is simply connected, by the monodromy theorem we have an analytic extension $f$ of $f_0$ defined on $\mathbb{D}$.

It remains to prove that $P\circ f=\text{Id}$. This follows from the identity principle, since it is true in $U_0$

2. Proof by means of the holomorphic lifting lemma

$(P^{-1}(\mathbb{D}),P)$ is a cover of $\mathbb{D}$, and since $\mathbb{D}$ is simply connected, there exists a function $f:\mathbb{D}\to P^{-1}(\mathbb{D})$ that lifts the identity, i.e. such that $f\circ P=\text{Id}$. However, since $P$ is locally invertible, and left and right inverse must be equal if they both exists, we have that, on $U_0$, $f=f_0$. The fact that $P\circ f=\text{Id}$ follows by the identity principle as in (1).

Comment: it is not true that $P(\mathbb D) \subset \mathbb D$ unless $p(z)=\alpha z, 0 \ne |\alpha| \le 1$ since if it were true $P$ would be injective on $\mathbb D$ since $P' \ne 0$ and it is not hard to show that if $P(a)=P(b), |a|,|b|<1$ there must be $|c|<1, P'(c)=0$ and then since $P^{-1}(\mathbb D) \subset \mathbb D$, $P$ has degree $1$

Comment: @Conrad I modified the argument accordingly

Comment: just wanted to add in the comment that your argument is generally correct and I will add another approach using normal families

Comment: Thank you for your help! Eventually I worked out the problem using Monodromy theorem. There are some delicacies if you write everything down precisely, but your comment definitely gives me a direction to start with.

Comment: @JasperLiang I noticed that after I wrote the answer, and I tried to add some of those details by proving that we can analytically extend $f_0$. The only thing missing is, while proving that $\Omega$ is closed, the existence of an analytic extension $f$ compatible with the "previous" ones. This is not hard to prove, but rather tedious.  If you have any notes, please go ahed.

Answer (score 2):

Let's give a slightly different solution than the ones above - note that if $0<r<1, C$ the unit circle, $P^{-1}(rC)$ is a union of $n=\deg P$ Jordan curves $J_1(r),...J_n(r) \subset \mathbb D$ and then $P^{-1}(r\mathbb D)$ is the union of their interiors

(since $P$ is a proper map the preimage is compact and by hypothesis, it is included in the open unit disc, hence each component is traversed only once as $P' \ne 0$ inside and on it, but $P$ is a $\deg P$ to $1$ map etc - more generally any level curve that doesn't contain a critical value of $P$, where $P$ is a proper analytic map on some domain, is a Jordan curve traversed $m+1$ times, where $m$ is the number of critical points of $P$ inside it).

In particular, if we fix $a \in P^{-1}(0)$ and take $J_1(r)$ the Jordan curve containing $a$ inside and $U_r$ its interior, we get a Riemann map $g_r:\mathbb D \to U_r$, hence $P\circ g_r$ is a conformal bijection of $\mathbb D$ onto $r\mathbb D$ and by composing with an automorphism of the unit disc we get $f_r:\mathbb D \to U_r$ with $P \circ f_r(z)=rz$. But $f_r$ is a normal family on the unit disc so taking a normally convergent subsequence of $f_{r_n}, r_n \to 1$ we get our $f$ for which $P\circ f(z)=z, z \in \mathbb D$

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It looks refreshing to me. Since both you and Caffeine sincerely answered the question, please forgive me for not clicking the "accept the answer" button, but I have upvoted your answer!

Comment: the problem was interesting and I am happy to be of help - it made me think more about level curves of polynomials