# inverse of an analytic function, analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

I've seen some papers recently where people seemed to be using the following fact, or something close to it, perhaps with a condition or two added.

Let f be entire with $f(0) = 0$, and suppose that $|f(w)| \geq r$ for any critical point $w$ of $f$. Then there is an inverse function $g(z)$ defined on the disk centered at $0$ with radius $r$ such that $f(g(z)) = z$.

I can see that there would locally be an inverse at each point there, and that somehow we are gluing them together, maybe using the monotomy theorem. But I've never fully understood this, in particular I don't see where the radius of convergence of $r$ for the inverse comes from. I can see, maybe, that critical values will give you trouble, but how do you know you can go all the way out until you hit one?

So, let's see how it applies. It seems easy enough to apply for a polynomial (although I still don't really know why it's true), and in fact this is the case I've seen it used for. But look now at $f(z) = e^z-1$. There are no critical points here, so clearly it doesn't quite work here, but maybe the problem is that the range of this function is $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{-1\}$, which is not simply connected. So now look at $f(z) = z e^z$. The range is now all of $\mathbb{C}$, but it now has a critical point at $z=-1$. The critical value is $-1/e$, so does that mean I'm guaranteed an injective inverse on the disk centered at 0 of radius $1/e$? If anyone can point me in the right direction on this I'll be quite grateful. A reference to a specific result would be great, but an explanation would be even better, as I'm a bit library-challenged these days. Thanks.

Greg

Comment: One needs an additional hypotesis for $g$ to make sense, i.e. that $f(\mathbb{C})$ contains the disk on which one wishes to define the function $g$ (since $f$ is entire and non constant, this is already "almost true" for every disc thanks to Picard's theorem). Otherwise, as you noted, $e^z-1$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: For a similar result (on polynomials, although some of the proofs there can easily be generalized with suitable hypotesis) see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644029/one-sided-inverse-of-a-complex-polynomial/3644826#3644826 .

Answer (score 2):

The problem with $f(z)=e^z-1$ is that the level curves $|f(z)|=r$ are not compact for $r=1$ so the proof below breaks down despite the fact that $f$ has no critical points.

If $0<r<1$ the level curves of $|f(z)|=r$ are Jordan curves (nonsingular closed curves on the Riemann sphere so if they are bounded in the plane as here they are Jordan) as $1+r \ge |e^z| \ge 1-r$ so $\log (1-r) \le \Re z \le \log(1+r)$ and if we take $J_r$ the one containing $0$ in $U_r$ its interior, then $e^z-1$ is invertible on $J_r$ hence on $U_r$ so the result holds by taking $\psi_r$ the unique Riemann map from $\mathbb D_r$ to $U_r, \psi_r (0)=0, \psi'(0) >0$ as $f \circ \psi_r$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb D_r$ fixing $0$ and with positive derivative at $0$ so it is the identity. Since the inverse is unique when it exists, it can be defined to $\mathbb D$ but now $U_1=\cup U_r$ is an unbounded simply connected domain containing $0$ where $f$ has an inverse.

Now let $f(z)=ze^z$; studying the equation $Ae^{-A}=r, r,A>0$ (since if $|z|=A, \min |f(z)|=Ae^{-A}$) we notice that it has solutions for $r \le \frac{1}{e}$ so in particular if $r < \frac{1}{e}$ there is $A<1, Ae^{-A}>r$ so the circle of radius $A$ separates $0$ from points where $|f(z)|=r, |z| >A$, hence if $J_r,U_r$ are the connected components of the circle/disc $f^{-1}(C_r), f^{-1}(\mathbb D_r), \partial \mathbb D_r =C_r$, $J_r$ is a Jordan curve (as it is closed nonsingular on the Riemann sphere and it is bounded in the plane so it doesn't go to infinity...) and $U_r$ is its interior. The same proof as above shows that $f$ has an inverse $\psi_r$ there and since the inverse is clearly unique when it exists, again we can extend it to $\mathbb D$ mapping into $\cup U_r$ which is now the bounded face of $J_{\frac{1}{e}}$ this last being the union of a closed curve and two non-intersecting arcs going to infinity and starting at $-1$ which touch the closed curve at $-1$

Edit later - I realized now that the OP asked also a general question and the answer is that as long as there are no critical values on $|f(z)|=r$, the components of $f^{-1}(C_r)$ are simple nonsingular curves but they may be unbounded (arcs going to infinity) rather than Jordan curves and only looking at a specific function/level curve we can tell.

Polynomials are proper maps (the only entire such functions) so we are guaranteed that we get Jordan curves as level curves at non-critical values.

The same analysis applies to meromorphic functions though now we have the added complications of poles so we may get multiply connected components with several Jordan curves on the boundary and also to holomorphic/meromorphic functions on domains (eg disc) where the level curves can intersect the boundary.

For example, the only proper holomorphic maps on the unit disc are finite Blaschke products (a theorem of Berman from the 1980's) so the level curves are always Jordan curves at non-critical values iff we deal with finite Blaschke products here (since the level curves at noncritical values are still nonsingular and simple but they may stop on the boundary rather than close up inside the domain)